# Rails has_many association with individual references

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can you create a `has_many` association but also be able to refer to the various instances by a term that isn't the name? Sort of like an attribute of the class? (`dog1` in this case.)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
  dogs: dog1, dog2, dog3, dog4 # I know this won't work but just to give the idea
end
```

So you can do:

```
barry = User.create(name: 'Barry')
barry.dog1.create(name: 'rover', weight: 12)
barry.dog1.name      #=> rover
barry.dog1.weight    #=> 12
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean way to do this in Rails, a workaround is to use `has_one`:

```
class User
  has_many :dogs
  has_one :favorite_dog, class_name: 'Dog', -> { where(favorite: true).order(updated_at: :desc) }
```

But, the thing is, Rails' `has_one` is just a `has_many` with a SQL `LIMIT 1`. So in fact, the relation `some_user.favorite_dog` will return only one record even though there could be several "favorited dogs". The `has_one :favorite_dog` I used as an example should be `latest_favorited_dog` (because of the order on `updated_at`).

`has_one` documentation: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one